# Pentaho Server error: A serious error occurred during job execution: Could not initialize class java.net.NetworkInterface

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I recently did a yum update all on one of my aws linux instances and rebooted my pentaho server. It was 200+ days since a reboot. I then tried to run my existing pentaho jobs and got this error in the carte.log file for any and all of my jobs.

log excerpt:

Job CIC_AgentActivityLog_job has failed!
Status: Finished (with errors)

Job log:
2018/04/27 22:36:25 - CIC_AgentActivityLog_job - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : A serious error occurred during job execution: Could not initialize class java.net.NetworkInterface
2018/04/27 22:36:25 - CIC_AgentActivityLog_job - ERROR (version 6.1.0.1-196, build 1 from 2016-04-07 12.08.49 by buildguy) : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.net.NetworkInterface
2018/04/27 22:36:25 - CIC_AgentActivityLog_job -        at org.pentaho.di.core.Const.getHostname(Const.java:1549)
2018/04/27 22:36:25 - CIC_AgentActivityLog_job -        at org.pentaho.di.core.KettleEnvironment.setExecutionInformation(KettleEnvironment.java:219)
2018/04/27 22:36:25 - CIC_AgentActivityLog_job -        at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.execute(Job.java:494)
2018/04/27 22:36:25 - CIC_AgentActivityLog_job -        at org.pentaho.di.job.Job.run(Job.java:435)}

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0):

I actually fixed this myself. Apparently I first ignored the errors during my yum update and issued the "# sudo yum update --skip-broken" command. I revisited this again and recorded the error from the yum update:

```
*Error: Package: libstdc++-devel-4.8.3-3.20.amzn1.noarch (@amzn-main)
           Requires: libstdc++48 = 4.8.3
           Removing: libstdc++48-4.8.3-9.111.amzn1.i686 (@amzn-main)
               libstdc++48 = 4.8.3-9.111.amzn1
           Updated By: libstdc++48-4.8.5-11.135.amzn1.i686 (amzn-main)
               libstdc++48 = 4.8.5-11.135.amzn1
Error: Package: libstdc++-devel-4.8.3-3.20.amzn1.noarch (@amzn-main)
           Requires: libstdc++48-devel = 4.8.3
           Removing: libstdc++48-devel-4.8.3-9.111.amzn1.x86_64 (@amzn-main)
               libstdc++48-devel = 4.8.3-9.111.amzn1
           Obsoleted By: gcc48-c++-4.8.5-11.135.amzn1.x86_64 (amzn-main)
               libstdc++48-devel = 4.8.5-11.135.amzn1
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest*
```

I then issued the following command:

sudo yum remove libstdc++-devel
sudo yum update

I restarted the server (AWS Linux) restarted the carte server and all was well in happy land. El Fin